# Как вывести информацию, после сравнения объекта с вводным значением

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, объекты

Имеется объект

```
var test = {
        'Петя' : {'h' : 170, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.2, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.790},
        'Вася' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840},
        'Юля' : {'h' : 150, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840},
        'Маша' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 36, 'b' : 36, 's' : 4.2 , 't' : 7.2, 'ves' : 5.820}
    };
```

Есть форма принимающая вводимые значения и присваивает их переменным a b s t.
Необходимо сравнивать значения из формы с элементами объекта и выносить значение элемента "ves".
Например: Вводим необходимые данные в форму. И если в объекте есть такие данные он выводит значение элемента "ves" соответствующего человека.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var test = {
        'Петя' : {'h' : 170, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.2, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.790},
        'Вася' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840},
        'Юля' : {'h' : 150, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840},
        'Маша' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 36, 'b' : 36, 's' : 4.2 , 't' : 7.2, 'ves' : 5.820}
};

var a=36, b=36, s=4.2, t=7.2;
var result = Object.keys(test).find(key => test[key].a == a && test[key].b == b && test[key].s == s && test[key].t == t);
console.log(result, test[result].ves);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const test = {
    'Петя' : {'h' : 170, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.2, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.790},
    'Вася' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840},
    'Юля' : {'h' : 150, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840},
    'Маша' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 36, 'b' : 36, 's' : 4.2 , 't' : 7.2, 'ves' : 5.820}
};
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const nameInput = document.getElementById('name');
form.onsubmit = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // отменяем действие по умолчанию
  const { value } = nameInput; // получаем значение инпута
  const result = test[value]; // получаем значение из объекта
  if (!result) alert('Не найдено!');
  else alert(result.ves);
}
```

```html
<form id='form'>
  <input id='name' placeholder='Имя' /><br/><br/>
  <button>Проверить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я хоть и опоздал, но вот мой вариант реализации: с инпутами и прочими ништяками, как и просили.

```js
var test = {
        'Петя' : {'h' : 170, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.2, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.790},
        'Вася' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840},
        'Юля' : {'h' : 150, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840},
        'Маша' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 36, 'b' : 36, 's' : 4.2 , 't' : 7.2, 'ves' : 5.820}
    };
let props=['a','b','s','t'],
inputs={},
res=$('#result')
props.forEach(v=>inputs[v]=$('input#'+v))
$('input').on('input',()=>{
  res.empty()
  for(let k in test){
    let obj=test[k]
    if(props.every(v=>inputs[v].val()==obj[v])) res.append('<p>Подходит '+k+', и его ves='+obj.ves+'</p>')
  }
})
```

```css
input{
  display:block;
  margin-top:4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="a" placeholder="a value">
<input id="b" placeholder="b value">
<input id="s" placeholder="s value">
<input id="t" placeholder="t value">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если есть объект ввода и по нему нужно найти:

```js
const test = {'Петя' : {'h' : 170, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.2, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.790}, 'Вася' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840}, 'Юля' : {'h' : 150, 'a' : 32, 'b' : 32, 's' : 4.4, 't' : 7, 'ves' : 4.840}, 'Маша' : {'h' : 165, 'a' : 36, 'b' : 36, 's' : 4.2 , 't' : 7.2, 'ves' : 5.820}}
const input = {a: 36, b: 36, s: 4.2, t: 7.2}

function find () {
  for (let obj of Object.values(test))
    if (Object.keys(input).every(i => input[i] === obj[i]))
      return obj.ves

  return null
}

console.log(find())
```